# Не понимаю как решить ошибку!

Tags: python, discord.py, discord, discord-api, disnake

Импортировать я не забыл))

```
from disnake import Option
```

Вот команда, из-за которой возникает ошибка:

```
async def trade(ctx,
                game: Option(name='game_name', type=str, description='Выбери игру из списка:', required=True, choices=['Dota 2', 'CS 2']),
                item_name: Option(name='item_name', type=str, description='Напишите название предмета', required=True),
                description: Option(name='desc', type=str, description='Опишите предмет который хотите обменять', required=False)):
```

продолжение у команды конечно есть, но оно думаю не нужно.

А вот ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\name\Desktop\Codes\!Sale_discrod_bots\testProjects\startNewProjects\tradeBot\main.py", line 41, in <module>
    async def trade(ctx,
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\interaction_bot_base.py", line 554, in decorator
    result = slash_command(
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\slash_core.py", line 820, in decorator
    return InvokableSlashCommand(
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\slash_core.py", line 452, in __init__
    options = expand_params(self)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\params.py", line 1031, in expand_params
    _, inter_param, params, injections = collect_params(command.callback)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\params.py", line 921, in collect_params
    elif parameter.annotation in Injection._registered:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Option'
```

Я пробовал обновить библиотеку, не помогло, думал не правильно импортировал или использовать Option, но все правильно. Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Ты пробовал добавить `from disnake import Option`?

Comment: Да, оно есть в самом начале ( здесь я вставил только команду)

Comment: Попробуй тогда заменить `Option`на `disnake.Option`

Comment: Та же самая ошибка(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Прочитав документацию](https://docs.disnake.dev/en/latest/ext/commands/slash_commands.html), я заметил, что `disnake.Option` нету в ней. Основываясь на документации, я написал данный код:

```py
@bot.slash_command(name="command")
async def trade( 
    ctx, 
    game: str = commands.Param(choices=[OptionChoice("Dota 2", "Dota 2"), OptionChoice("CS2", "CS2")]), 
    item_name: str = commands.Param(), 
    description: str = None):
    """
    Описание команды

    Parameters
    ----------
    game: Описание game
    item_name: Описание item_name
    description: Описание description
    """
    ...
```

И используя данный код, все у вас должно быть, как вы хотите. То есть, выбор CS2 или Dota 2 *(обязательный)*, название предмета *(тоже обязательный)* и описание *(не обязательно)*.

[image: Угу.]

Comment: disnake.Option не существует? Мне как то наоборот сказали использовать его

Comment: Здравствуйте, да, Я сказал, что можете попробовать использовать `disnake.Option`, но до этого я не прочитал документацию. Сейчас, углубившись в нее, я понял, что тот комментарий неправилен. Крайне извиняюсь за свою ошибку

Comment: А это были вы?) Ладно, спасибо!

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста. Рад помочь 

Answer (score 1):

Я конечно понимаю, что я немного поздно, но всё равно напишу ответ, может кому-то поможет..

`disnake.Option` нужно использовать не в параметрах функции, а в декораторе, определяющий функцию как слэш команду.

Вот пример:

```py
@commands.slash_command(
    name="send_report",
    description="command description",
    options=[
        disnake.Option(
            name="message", description="message option description", required=True),
        disnake.Option(
            name="report_type", description="report type message description", 
            choices=bot_choices.CHOICE_FOR_REPORT_TYPE, required=True)
    ]
)
async def send_report(self, ctx, message: str, report_type: str):
    [...]
```

Еще параметры `name` и `description` из `disnake.Option` могут быть локализированы через `disnake.Localized`.